# Email send with PDF Attachment

Tags: email, email-template, pdf, apex-email-service, pagereference

I have a VF page with below custom controller. I am not getting the exact point why the email is not getting generated. Can someone please help?

**Apex Controller**

```
public with sharing class CaptureEmailController1 {
    public String selectedMailId {get;set;}
    public String selectedTemplateId { get; set;}
    Account a;
    public Map<Id,EmailTemplate> etMap{get;set;}
    public String AttachPage{get;set;}
    ID accountID;
    Account listOfEmail;
    public String inputEmailId{set;get;}
    public String subject{get;set;}
    public String body{get;set;}
    public Boolean sendEmail{get;set;}

    public void ApplyTemplate()
    {
        String selId = selectedTemplateId;

            Subject = etMap.get(selId).Subject;
        Body = etMap.get(selId).Body;  
        AttachPage =  etMap.get(selId).Description;  
    }

    public List<SelectOption> getTemplateOptions() {
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();

        for (EmailTemplate t : etMap.values()) {
        System.debug(t.Name);

                options.add(new SelectOption(t.Id,t.Name));
                if((selectedTemplateId == '' || selectedTemplateId == null))
                {
                    selectedTemplateId = t.Id;
                    ApplyTemplate();
                }
         }
        return options;
    }    

    public CaptureEmailController1(){
        a = new Account();
        selectedMailId = '';
        inputEmailId = '';
        subject = '';
        body = '';
        accountID = '.....'; // ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')

        etMap = new Map<Id,EmailTemplate>([SELECT 
        Body , Description , DeveloperName , FolderId , Id , Name , OwnerId , Subject , TemplateType  FROM 
        EmailTemplate where Folder.Name = 'Sample Form' and TemplateType  = 'Text']);
    } 
     public list<SelectOption> getListOfEmail(){
        List<SelectOption> emailOptionList = new List<SelectOption>();
        emailOptionList.add(new SelectOption('', 'Select a value', true));

        String query = 'SELECT ';       
List<Schema.FieldSetMember> fieldSetMemberList =  Utilitiesclass.readFieldSet('CaptureEmail_ax','Account');
for(Schema.FieldSetMember fieldSetMemberObj : fieldSetMemberList)
{   

    query += fieldSetMemberObj.getFieldPath() + ', ';

    system.debug('API Name ====>' + fieldSetMemberObj.getFieldPath()); //api name
    system.debug('Label ====>' + fieldSetMemberObj.getLabel());
    system.debug('Required ====>' + fieldSetMemberObj.getRequired());
    system.debug('DbRequired ====>' + fieldSetMemberObj.getDbRequired());
    system.debug('Type ====>' + fieldSetMemberObj.getType());   //type - STRING,PICKLIST

   }

         query =query + 'Id, Name FROM account where  id =\''+ accountID +'\'';

        listOfEmail = Database.query(query);
for(Schema.FieldSetMember fieldSetMemberObj : fieldSetMemberList)
{ String Value = String.valueOf(listOfEmail.get(fieldSetMemberObj.getFieldPath()));
  if(Value!=null)
  emailOptionList.add(new SelectOption(Value,Value,false));

}
        emailOptionList.add(new SelectOption('Others', 'Others', false));
        return emailOptionList;
    }

    void prepareEmailIds() {
        CaptureEmailObj_ax__c captureEmailObj1 = new CaptureEmailObj_ax__c();
        captureEmailObj1.Account_ax__c = accountID;
        if(selectedMailId != '' && selectedMailId != 'Others'){
            system.debug('selectedMailId@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ ' + selectedMailId);
            captureEmailObj1.Sent_Email_ax__c = selectedMailId;
        }
        else if(inputEmailId != ''){
            system.debug('inputEmailId@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ ' + inputEmailId);

           // Checking email pattern
            String emailRegex = '^[a-zA-Z0-9._|\\\\%#~`=?&/$^*!}{+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$';
            Pattern MyPattern = Pattern.compile(emailRegex);
            Matcher MyMatcher;
            MyMatcher = MyPattern.matcher(inputEmailId);
            if (!MyMatcher.matches())
            {
                system.debug('pattern does not match@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ ' );
                ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR, 'Invalid Email Addresses: ' + inputEmailId));
                return;
            } else{            
                system.debug('pattern matched@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ ' );
                ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.INFO, 'Your data is successfully updated!'));
                captureEmailObj1.Sent_Email_ax__c = inputEmailId; 
                captureEmailObj1.Subject_ax__c = subject;
                captureEmailObj1.Body_ax__c = body;    
                insert captureEmailObj1;
            }
        }

        return;        


    }



     public PageReference send() {

        InputEmailId = '';
        prepareEmailIds();
        if(InputEmailId=='')
        {

            return null;
        } 
       try
        {       PageReference Pdf = new PageReference('/apex/.....'); 
                Pdf.getParameters().put('templateid', '...');
                pdf.setRedirect(true);//false

                Blob b = pdf.getContent();
                system.debug('@b'+b);

                Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();

                efa.setFileName('SampleFormTemplateView.pdf');
                efa.setBody(b);    
                system.debug('@efa'+efa);
                 Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();                
                email.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] {efa});        


            // Sets the paramaters of the email
            email.setSubject(Subject);
            List<String> sendTo = new List<String>();
      sendTo.add('abc@co.com');     //selectedMailId       
            email.setToAddresses( sendTo  ); // 


            email.setPlainTextBody( Body);

            Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r = 
            Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email});   
            sendEmail=true;//Control viz of Send btn.
            ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.INFO, 'Your Email has been successfully Sent'));

            //sendEmail=true;
        }

        catch(Exception x)
        {
             ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR, 'Exception:' + x.getMessage()));
        }

        return null;
    }

    // Clicking on cancel will redirect to account page
    public PageReference cancel(){
        PageReference pg = new PageReference('/' + accountID);
        pg.setRedirect(true);
        return pg;
    }

}
```

Comment: Any Exceptions? Please explain where you're getting the problem? What are your observations from Debug Logs?

Comment: Simply not getting send method in debug logs. Where am I wrong I am not getting frnd!

Comment: Are you trying to use `getcontentaspdf()` which is now a callout or are you trying to render a specific page and attach it to an email? It unclear to me what you're trying to do. Is this a generic method for use from any page or is there a page and template you're using for it?